# Mysql - Concat - Procedure execution failed

Tags: mysql, triggers, procedure, concatenation

I have 123 tables as well: M001 -> M010 -> M123.
each is a client. when it reaches a record to a parent table with a trigger call a function like this:

```
  Declare MasterX  int;
  Set MasterX = New.Master;
  Call Lecturas_Insertar(MasterX,New.Id);
```

This is my function:

```
BEGIN

#Set Master
  If MasterX < 10 Then 
  Set MasterX = Concat("lecturas.M00",MasterX);
  End If;
#Set Master
  If MasterX Between 10 and 99 Then 
  Set MasterX = Concat("lecturas.M0",MasterX);
  End If;

  set @a=concat("INSERT INTO ",MasterX, "(Id) Values(" ,Id, ")");
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
  EXECUTE stmt1; 
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END
```

But it always throws me the following error:

```
  Procedure execution failed
  1146 - Table 'lecturas.M' does not exist
```

Thanks for the Help of All

Comment: You concat `MasterX` number value with a string 'lecturas.M0'. What did you expect?

Comment: Can save the record in the table lecturas.M00123 or lecturas.M0013 or lecturas.M001, depending on the MasterX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script -

```
BEGIN
  SET @a = CONCAT('INSERT INTO lecturas.M', LPAD(MasterX, 3, 0), '(Id) Values(', Id, ')');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
  EXECUTE stmt1; 
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```